# jQuery, on rollover text or image link, dim text and linked image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have menu links with corresponding images. I am trying to connect the text link to the image so when either the text link or the image is rolled-over, the other text and the image dims but not the main. Thanks for the help.

I have a partial demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/d23UE/
When I rollover either the text or the img, all seems to dim.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".together li a").hover(function () {
        $(".together li a").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.4
        }, 400);
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1);
    },

    function () {
        $(".together li a").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 400);
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="buttons" class="together">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Button 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Button 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Button 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="images" class="together">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="Button-1-image.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="Button-2-image.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="Button-3-image.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The JSFiddle code seems to work OK as expected. What issues are you having?

Comment: Hi Dennis, I would like the corresponding image to not dim. Currently, all images dim when I hover the text links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by grabbing the index of the hovered element, then fading out only the list elements that *didn't* have that same index:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".together li a").hover(function () {
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('.together').each(function (i, el) { //restart index counting for each list
      $('li:not(:eq(' + idx + '))', el).stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 400);
    });
  },

  function () {
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('.together').each(function (i, el) {
      $('li:not(:eq(' + idx + '))', el).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/d23UE/2/

Comment: Blazemonger, thanks for your quick solution. It seems to work great. I appreciate you help.

Comment: Blazemonger, I have another help request. I added a submenu to the text link but do not want them to dim along with the rest. I did not want to impose on you again... Thanks again.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432418/jquery-rollover-text-or-image-link-dim-text-and-linked-image-with-sub-menu

http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/bWYwn/67/