# jQuery - Rollover text or image link, dim text and linked image with sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a menu where the text link and image link are linked together. By rolling on either the text or image link, the other text and images dim.

I am trying to have the sub-links for each main link fadeIn when rolled-over text or image links.

**Question**: I need help getting the specific div sub-menu to show when the link or image is rolled-over.
http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/bWYwn/67/. Thanks for your help.

```
<ul id="buttons" class="together">
<li><a href="#">Button 1</a>
    <ul id="button-1-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Button 2</a>
    <ul id="button-2-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Button 3</a>
    <ul id="button-3-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul id="button-images" class="together">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Button-1-image.jpg" width="50px" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Button-2-image.jpg" width="50px" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="Button-3-image.jpg" width="50px" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)?

Comment: 3dgoo, my question has been revised above. Thanks for your help.